# Elm: avoiding a Maybe check each time

Tags: elm

I am building a work-logging app which starts by showing a list of projects that I can select, and then when one is selected you get a collection of other buttons, to log data related to that selected project.

I decided to have a `selected_project : Maybe Int` in my model (projects are keyed off an integer id), which gets filled with `Just 2` if you select project 2, for example.

The buttons that appear when a project is selected send messages like `AddMinutes 10` (i.e. log 10 minutes of work to the selected project).

Obviously the update function will receive one of these types of messages only if a project has been selected but I still have to keep checking that `selected_project` is a `Just p`.

Is there any way to avoid this?

One idea I had was to have the buttons send a message which contains the project id, such as `AddMinutes 2 10` (i.e. log 10 minutes of work to project 2). To some extent this works, but I now get a duplication -- the `Just 2` in the `model.selected_project` and the `AddMinutes 2 ...` message that the button emits.

### Update

As Simon notes, the repeated check that `model.selected_project` is a `Just p` has its upside: the model stays relatively more decoupled from the UI. For example, there might be other UI ways to update the projects and you might not need to have first selected a project.

Comment: Being able to press the button when no project is selected seems like an invalid thing to do. How about disabling the `AddMinutes` button when no project is selected? Having the project ID as part of the `AddMinutes` message does not seem like a bad idea; you could have this message originate from somewhere else uncoupled from this particular UI. The project you selected and the project you're adding minutes to happen to be the same in your current UI.

Comment: Agreed, this is what I thought too. But I was also wondering if there is some way to enter another ‘project selected’ state where those buttons exist and the messages/update function know that a project is definitely selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid having to check the `Maybe` each time you need a function which puts you into a context wherein the value "wrapped" by the `Maybe` is available. That function is `Maybe.map`.

In your case, to handle the `AddMinutes Int` message you can simply call: `Maybe.map (functionWhichAddsMinutes minutes) model.selected_project`.

Clearly, there's a little bit more to it since you have to produce a model, but the point is you can use `Maybe.map` to perform an operation if the value is available in the `Maybe`. And to handle the `Maybe.Nothing` case, you can use `Maybe.withDefault`.

At the end of the day is this any better than using a case expression? Maybe, maybe not (pun intended).

Personally, I have used the technique of providing the ID along with the message and I was satisfied with the result.